# Compartilhando um projeto sem determinados módulos

Tags: git, versionamento, gitlab

Tenho um projeto em andamento versionado, tudo direitinho, com vários módulos e cada módulo possui várias funcionalidades e preciso compartilhar o projeto com uma outra equipe, porém essa equipe não precisa de certos módulos, até ai tudo bem, o problema é que se for desenvolvido mais funcionalidades para um módulo que a outra equipe possui preciso que eles tenham acesso a essas novas implementações. 
Qual o mais correto a se prosseguir?
Fazer um fork do projeto atual e remover as funcionalidades desse novo fork por exemplo e toda vez que implementar uma funcionalidade passa essa funcionalidade pro outro projeto? Ou tem outra solução mais eficiente? Se sim, qual o comando ou a maneira mais eficiente de prosseguir?

Comment: Por que não deixar tudo visível e deixar eles trabalharem no fluxo gitflow, alterando em seus feature-branches apenas o módulo a que eles deveriam ter mudar? Isso pode ser garantido através da política de revisão/merge do mantenedor do código

Comment: O problema é que eles não pode ter acesso a determinados módulos nem acesso ao código do sistema

Comment: Então um simples `fork` não será o suficiente. Porque no git se mantém todo o histórico do que aconteceu. Particularmente eu sou contra essa estratégia de esconder código, quanto mais aberto melhor. Se eles realmente não precisam enxergar, vejo duas possibilidades: refazer o histórico localmente (dá um trabalho **muito** grande, mas é possível) e subir em um novo repositório OU fazer um repositório novinho em folha com o primeiro commit sendo _apenas_ o módulo em questão. Mas reflita com seu gerente a necessidade de esconder o código, sou partidário que normalmente não é necessário

Comment: a questão de esconder o código nesse caso é necessária pois se trata de um setor de inteligência governamental, o problema maior que eu vejo é no caso de implementar as funcionalidades no módulo que as duas equipes possuem, eu teria que fazer o commit nos dois projetos

Comment: Dá para tentar compartilhando só o submódulo específico. O commit seria único, mas o repositório "agregador" precisaria ser notificado que o módulo foi atualizado. Seria usando o [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v1/Ferramentas-do-Git-Subm%C3%B3dulos). Interessa? Vou demorar um pouco para compor a resposta, se interessar

Comment: não sabia dessa funcionalidade, se não for pedir muito, ajudaria de mais!